# Отношения в таблицах. Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помоги разобраться с теорией и с тем, как применить её в Laravel 5.

Есть три таблицы: Люди (Вася, Петя, Маша), юзеры системы (Вася, Маша), роли (Дворник, Старший дворник, Самый старший дворник).

Люди: id, name, surname, id_role.
Юзеры: id, email, password, id_people.
Роли: id, name.

Есть много много людей. У каждого человека есть роль. Некоторые из этих людей могут зайти в систему по логину и паролю и в зависимости от роли иметь какие-то ограничения.

Как мне получить роль Юзера Васи? То есть получается надо сперва вытащить id_pople, затем найти запись в Людях, затем там вытащить id_role и только потом вернуть name у роли?

Answer (score 0):

Если связи прописаны корректно, то обычно достаточно примерно такого:

```
$role_name = User::whereId($vasya_id)->people()->role()->name;
```